# Go over JSON object with running index

Tags: javascript, json, angular, for-loop

I have the following JSON :

```js
var myObj;
myObj = {
    "name": "A",
    "r1":"y",
    "r2":"n",
    "r3":"y",
    "lname": "B"
};

//And I want to iterate on this object by for loop as follows:

         for (var j=1 ; j<= 3 ; j++)
         {
            var tmpR = "r" + j;
            if(myObj.tmpR == "y")
            {
              //some code...
            }
         }
```

It doesn't work, I am allways get `"undefined"`, If I put `"r1"` for example instead of `tmpR` it's OK.

How can I iterate on this object ?
I don't want to write seperate if for `r1, r2` and so on.

Answer (score 3):

in the code you are searching for a key named 'tmpR' in object which doesn't exist, you need to use bracket notation.

```js
var myObj;
myObj = {
    "name": "A",
    "r1":"y",
    "r2":"n",
    "r3":"y",
    "lname": "B"
};

for (var j = 1; j <= 3; j++) {
    var tmpR = "r" + j;
    if(myObj[tmpR] == "y") {
        console.log('key: ' + tmpR + ' value: ' + myObj[tmpR]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the individual properties of the object, then you can use the index operator like `myObj['r1']`.  For example your loop could look like:

```
for (var j = 1; j <= 3; j++) {
  var tmpR = "r" + j;
  var r = myObj[tmpR];
  if (r == "y") {
    //some code...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a property which does not exist in your jason object. You need to do this:

```
for (var j=1 ; j<= 3 ; j++) {
        if(myObj['r'+j] === "y") {
          //some code...
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to access properties of an object, as mentioned [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

As you want to access object property with a dynamic variable, you have to use the **Bracket notation**.

You can see the example, which is written in a more functional way:

```
const myObj = {
    "name": "A",
    "r1":"y",
    "r2":"n",
    "r3":"y",
    "lname": "B"
};

[1,2,3].map(n => `r${n}`)
       .filter(k => myObj[k] === 'y')
       .forEach(k => console.log(`Key: ${k} - value: ${myObj[k]}`));
```